# Automapper: Missing TypeMap configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper-2

```
// HomeController.cs
[AutoMap(typeof(Test), typeof(TestViewModel))]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var tests = new List<Test>();
    tests.Add(new Test());
    return View(tests);
}

// Index.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<AutoMapperTest.Models.TestViewModel>

// AutoMapper Configuration
CreateMap<Test, TestViewModel>();

// Automapper configuration test is fine
[TestMethod]
public void Should_map_dtos()
{
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

[AutoMapAttribute](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) taken from here.

If the action return 'Test' it works. If it returns 'IEnumerable' it doesn't (view changed to expect TestViewModel and IEnumerable obviously). What am I doing wrong? From what I understand I don't need to explicitly map List types.

This probably has a simple answer but have spent the last two hours trying to get this to work so would much appreciate someone pointing me to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your description whether or not you changed the AutoMapper attribute to include the List or not:

```
[AutoMapper(typeof(List<Test>), typeof(List<TestViewModel>)]
```

Comment: I knew it was something silly like this. I just assumed, the attribute did not require including the list. Many thanks.